# mysql suddently not starting in xampp (WINDOWS)

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

I went to start xampp and suddenly mysql isn't starting. This happened the other day, I deleted the ib_logfiles and restarated it, and that worked. But that isn't working this time. I tried copying everything from backup to the data folder, but when I log into localhost, it is asking me to reinstall wordpress, which isn't what I want either. I've looked through countless posts but nothing people are recommending seems to work.

I am not a coder by any means. This is my first time using a localhost to build a website.

Here's the error:

```
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 4712
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-10-04 13:48:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 301077; transaction id 8
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231004 13:48:35
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2023-10-04 13:48:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I was trying to start my locally hosted website using xampp. I expected mysql to start as normal, but it failed to load.

Comment: I had a preview Windows update install about a week ago.  I then had a .NET update install and after the reboot MySQL would not start anymore.  I use IIS but I had to do a system restore to get MySQL to load.

Comment: @CharlesEF Thanks. I checked, but that isn't the case for me.

Comment: The error log points that exist problems with two tables in your mysql database (see the [ERROR] indications in the log): mysql.plugin and mysql.servers. Besides, you are telling that, after restoring a backup of the mysql database (that comes with Xampp package, right?), the first problem disappears: mysql starts again!. So , it seems that your major problem is that not only your mysql database is corrupted, but probably your WordPress's database is corrupted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database was corrupted. I've stopped using XAMPP and have switched to Local by Flywheel.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem today, posting it here my work-around.
Check for path `xampp/mysql/data/multi-master.info` file exists, and *rename/delete* it.
This worked for me.